# Press X to exit or any other key to continue?

Tags: powershell

Grrr...  Noob question here.  I want to create a block that basically does this:

```
Write-Host "Press X to cancel or any other key to continue"
$continue = Read-Host
  If ($continue = "X") 
     {exit}
  else 
     {Write-Host "Hello world"}
```

Keeps exiting even if I press another key...  What am I doing wrong?   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use "-eq" for comparsion. Simple example:

```
$a = "Powershell"
IF ($a -eq "PowerShell")
{
 "Statement is True"
}
ELSE
{
 "Statement is False"
}
```

Here is some reading to be confident with "if-then-else" statements: [IF_THEN_ELSE in Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/flaphead/archive/2006/09/12/455555.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  -eq vs. "=" was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator is for assignment.  Use `-eq` to test for equality.

Comment: Got it... Thanks!  I knew I was close.  :)